# Split a list by the type of element

Tags: java, list, guava

For the code snippet below:

```
List<ParentClass> ls = new ArrayList<ParentClass>();
ls.add(new ChildClass1());
ls.add(new ChildClass2());
ls.add(new ChildClass1());
ls.add(new ChildClass2());
ls.add(new ChildClass2());
ls.add(new ChildClass1());
ls.add(new ChildClass2());

List<ChildClass1> sub1 = new ArrayList<ChildClass1>();
List<ChildClass2> sub2 = new ArrayList<ChildClass2>();
for (ParentClass p : ls) {
    if(p instanceof ChildClass1){
        sub1.add((ChildClass1)p);
    } else {
        sub2.add((ChildClass2)p);
    }
}       

System.out.println(sub1);
System.out.println(sub2);
```

Is there an elegant way to get sub1 and sub2? I did tried Guava Collections2.filter() which returned Collection《ParentClass》, while I need Collection《ChildClass1》, any idea?

```
Collection<ParentClass> sub1= Collections2.filter(ls, Predicates.instanceOf(ChildClass1.class))
```

Comment: If you can get away with an `Iterable` instead of a `Collection`, you can just use `Iterables.filter(ls, ChildClass1.class)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something along this line should work

```
Collection<ChildClass1> sub1 = ls.stream()
                                 .filter (x -> x instanceof ChildClass1)
                                 .map ( x-> (ChildClass1) x)
                                 .collect(Collectors.asList());
```

Comment: Thank you for this lambda exp, this only works on JDK8, right?

Comment: Yes, but you can probably do something similar in `Guava`

Answer (score 2):

Using Guava and single-pass you can perform an index operation:

```
ImmutableListMultimap<Class<?>, ? extends ParentClass> index = FluentIterable.from(ls)
        .index(Object::getClass);
List<ChildClass1> sub1 = (List<ChildClass1>) index.get(ChildClass1.class);
List<ChildClass2> sub2 = (List<ChildClass2>) index.get(ChildClass2.class);
```

Prior to Java-8 replace `Object::getClass` with anonymous class:

```
ImmutableListMultimap<Class<?>, ? extends ParentClass> index = FluentIterable.from(ls)
        .index(new Function<ParentClass, Class<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Class<?> apply(ParentClass o) {
                return o.getClass();
            }
        });
```

The Stream API equivalent is the following:

```
Map<?, List<ParentClass>> map = ls.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getClass));
List<ChildClass1> sub1 = (List<ChildClass1>) (List<?>)map.get(ChildClass1.class);
List<ChildClass2> sub2 = (List<ChildClass2>) (List<?>)map.get(ChildClass2.class);
```

Unfortunately the unchecked cast is still necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The "guava"-est way to do it is the following:

```
List<ParentClass> ls = ... ;
FluentIterable<ParentClass> it = FluentIterable.from(ls);

List<ChildClass1> sub1 = it.filter(ChildClass1.class).toList();
List<ChildClass2> sub2 = it.filter(ChildClass2.class).toList();
```

Note that it results in two distinct iterations (or actually the number of times you call `toList()`).

If you require only one iteration, I'm afraid that the only solution so far is exactly what you wrote in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Guava assumes that if you are filtering elements of type `T` then as a result you will still get a collection of `T` (a subcollection of the original collection). It cannot infer by any means that the `Predicates.instanceOf(SubT.class)` filter leads to a safe type conversion, even though it will indeed produce a list of `SubT`. So you need to make an explicit cast to `Collection<ChildClass1>` yourself. Or, to be precise - first cast to a raw list, then to `Collection<ChildClass1>` to work around compiler type checks.

```
Collection<ChildClass1> sub1= (Collection<ChildClass1>) (Collection) Collections2.filter(ls, Predicates.instanceOf(ChildClass1.class))
```